# Rails sort listing using up and down arrow

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to sort my listing using up and down arrow means with every row record there will be two arrow up and down arrow .and user can sort his listing using arrow and this order should be get saved in data base .

[image]

Help me with some code if any one has already done this.

Answer (score 2):

You will probably want to add some method of storing configurable ordering in the DB, and then implement some JS to manage requests to change the order (and maybe update the view too).

Check out the `acts_as_list` gem [1], which will add a `position` column to your orderable model and give you functionality to move items in the list.

Then look at using AJAX to manage the calls to move up/down. There's lots of tutorials out there (this one from 2009, so a little old now, but the principle is the same [2])

[1] https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list

[2] http://railscasts.com/episodes/147-sortable-lists

Comment: thanks Pavling ..but i have resolved the issue using ajax without using any gem.

Comment: yup, rolling your own `position` field and `move` methods is fine too :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add ajax to your arrows, which calls a `move function` to sub 1 from the "position column" and adds one to the one you have above. Like this:

```
YourModel.find_by(position: your-position-1).update(position: position+10101010) #10101010 is just a big number which I of, that your table isn't that long.
YourModel.find_by(position: your-position).update(position: your-position-1)
YourModel.find_by(position: position+10101010).update(position: your-position)
```

This is a simple exchange algorithm.
 The next step is just to update your Table with Ajax.